# Is it possible to serve a website on a TLD?

Tags: domain-name-system, tld

I have never seen a website hosted on a TLD (for example: http://com or http://ru)

Is this even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create a top level TLD? (.michael for instance)](http://serverfault.com/questions/243316/can-i-create-a-top-level-tld-michael-for-instance)

Comment: I made my question more specific, it's not a duplicate now.

Comment: My main concern is **serving** on a TLD.

Answer (score 6):

It's technically possible, but not recommended. For the new gTLDs, the agreements between the domain holders and ICANN even forbids doing it.

Answer (score 5):

From a DNS perspective, it's possible for `A` records to exist at the TLD level. In practice, the registries do not do so.

Instead of appropriating the apex, registries typically reserve a subdomain within their own TLD for administrative use. A common convention is to host this under the `nic` subdomain (*Network Information Center*), with `nic.uk` being an example of such.

**Caution:** The practice of reserving the `nic` subdomain is *not* standardized. One should not assume that such a website is operated by a registry entity, with `nic.com` being an example of one that is not.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to create AAAA and A records on a TLD. There are a few TLDs which already do this and run a webserver on the address. Generally those will simply server a redirect to the website of the registrar for that TLD. One example of this is http://dk./

It would even be possible to create AAAA and A records on `.`, but that hasn't been done, and it seems unlikely that would ever happen. If it did happen you could even imagine a website on the address http://./.

But lots of software is going to treat such domains differently from how you would want it to. For example software may apply heuristics to decide whether a string is a domain or not by looking for the presence of a `.` character. Moreover if software does consider a string without a `.` to be a domain name in the first place, another layer of the software may decide that due to the absence of a `.` it has to be subject to your DNS search configuration.

Those are the reasons I wrote `dk.` in the above example rather than just `dk`. In short it is possible but not very useful. And getting your own TLD is expensive.